# PowerChute Personal on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ups, apc-powerchute

APC UPS PowerChute Personal edition battery is not visible  under the Configuaration> Power Options under Advanced Settings Balanced Power plan. The Battery Option should be visible to configure:

```
 Critical battery action
 Low battery level
 Critical battery level
 low battery notification
  low battery action
  reserve battery level
```